# open sets of infinite produduct: $[0,1]^{\omega _1}$

Tags: general-topology

I am  studying  a paper and  where  assuming  Continuum  Hypothesis (CH). Author writes "every open set $U$ in $[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ is countable union of basic open sets.

I do not  know how to prove it.

I  worked using the fact  that $[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ is separable and $[0,1]$ has countable basis (space $[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ is not 2-countable ) but  I did not get to prove.

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ does not have that property. Every open set $O$ does contain a countable union of basic open sets that is dense in $O$; this follows from ccc, essentially.

Comment: An addendum to "$[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ does not have that property": The complement of a singleton is open but not a countable union of basic open sets.